# Wait for all items added to buffered channel

Tags: go

I have implemented WaitGroup but it doesn't work as expected, I need to print all 1000 logs but actual result is just ~9xx logs, I know the root cause is the first gorouting hasn't been finished yet while the rest of goroutines in the loop of buffered channel have been done

How do I solve this problem? Thanks in advance

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    buffer := make(chan int, 5)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        for i := 1; i <= 1000; i++ {
            buffer <- i
        }

        close(buffer)
        wg.Done()
    }(&wg)

    for item := range buffer {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup, item int) {
            log.Printf("done for item %d\n", item)
            wg.Done()
        }(&wg, item)
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

**Updated**

I found the problem, I run the codes in GoLand IDE and it doesn't print all the logs, if I run in terminal it should be fine

Comment: This should print everything in the channel. Are you aware that the items don't print in any particular order?

Comment: @Peter yes the wrong orders are fine with me, I just need to print all of them (1000 items) without using time.Sleep() to wait :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any issue with the waitgroup and it is printing all 1000 logs on go [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/nVNNNuuwXjk).

Comment: I found the problem, I run the codes in GoLand IDE and it doesn't print all the logs, if I run in terminal it should be fine

Answer (score 1):

but it's already happening.

As it's not ordered properly, I think it's misleading to you think that it's only printing ~9xx logs.

I ran it and I got (Full output not shown):

```
2020/06/03 10:38:35 done for item 986
2020/06/03 10:38:35 done for item 988
2020/06/03 10:38:35 done for item 1000
2020/06/03 10:38:35 done for item 995
2020/06/03 10:38:35 done for item 993
2020/06/03 10:38:35 done for item 996
2020/06/03 10:38:35 done for item 997
2020/06/03 10:38:35 done for item 991
2020/06/03 10:38:35 done for item 998
2020/06/03 10:38:35 done for item 990
2020/06/03 10:38:35 done for item 992
2020/06/03 10:38:35 done for item 999
2020/06/03 10:38:35 done for item 989
2020/06/03 10:38:35 done for item 412
```

> *Notice*: 1000 is there.

If you want to confirm:

```sh
go run main.go &> sample.txt // Redirects the output of the executable to sample.txt
cat sample.txt | wc -l       // Counts the number of lines in output
```

It's 1000.

Comment: I found the problem, I run the codes in GoLand IDE and it doesn't print all the logs, if I run in terminal it should be fine